# Connecting IBAction to a button in xcode5

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've been following this guide carefully and I got stuck here.
Click [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/25561/learn-to-code-ios-apps-3-your-first-app)
When I try to connect press ctrl and drag on my button, a popup comes up giving me options "Leading space to container, Center Vertically in container, Equal widths, equal height Aspect ratio" I don't see the option to press my button like in the guide. I read the comments below and it seems like everyone is having this problem. I know it's an old guide so that's probably the reason why

Comment: **"I know it's an old guide but *I like it*."** This is stopping you from finding another more relevant and helpful one?

Comment: I've tried looking, believe me

Comment: [Really?](http://codewithchris.com/demo-app-with-xcode-and-interface-builder/)

Answer (score 2):

Just right click on the button and then you can normally drag from `touchUpInside` action to your view controller.

[image]

Comment: I got to touchupinside and not sure what to do from there

Answer (score 0):

Instead of control-dragging from the storyboard to the storyboard, open up the Assistant Editor with the .m/.h file you want the action code to be in, and control-drag the button from the storyboard to somewhere in that document. Then you should be able to pick between IBOutlet and IBAction.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will create your (IBAction) functionName:(id)sender { } for you

Comment: I got them open side by side and when I try to control drag it won't link.

Comment: Do you have the correct file open? Is the .h/.m the viewController file for your specified view you're trying to place the button in?

Comment: Yes. I followed the guide very carefully,I have view controller.h open

Comment: Did you get the labels to work (the section before adding buttons)?

Comment: Yes I added to the labels on the story board, then the buttons. After it was asking me to connect the buttons first

Comment: When you are looking at the storyboard view with your button, try dragging the button to the yellow view controller button below the view (make sure you have the IBAction function predefined like in the tutorial). I think what may be happening is that you are control dragging and clicking the view, not the actual controller so it displays constraint information as opposed to function information, but that's just a slightly education guess :-)